# How to resume a process from an SSH connection?

Tags: process

At work, I have lot's of interactive scripts running that I would like to access them later on from home. If I do `Ctrl+Z` to them and then `bg`, then I am able to use them from home using the `fg` command. However, I usually forget to put them in the background. Can I resume them later on (from Home) knowing just their PID or something ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you. Which are the state of the processes you are trying to resume? Stopped? Why can't you resume them using `[bg | fg] %<job_number>` from your SSH connection? What's the problem?

Comment: You should probably consider something like [`screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), if you often need to suspend and bring back processes across sessions.

Comment: Also [search for reptyr here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=reptyr+is%3Aanswer), which is one of the usual solutions to (many) very similar questions.

Comment: People have been using `tmux` and its further build `byobu` for this for a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I resume them later on (from Home) knowing just their PID or something ?

No, since the scripts are tied to the terminal from which you run them.

However, you can run your scripts inside `tmux` or `screen`.  You can then detach `tmux` / `screen` from the terminal, and re-attach to it later from home.  This one of the main use cases for `tmux` and `screen`.